# Intellij IDEA - eclipse-like debugging (after launch code change)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

### I don't remember the name of this feature on Eclipse but it is something like that:

- start 'Debug build'
- Change code
- reapply changes *(still running that same debug build)*
- Now you can see the change in 'real time' without having to close the application and having to 'go' to the point you wanted

How can I do this in Intellij IDEA (and if it is possible to do using LibGDX applications)

Comment: Probably you mean Eclipse's 'Debug Shell'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is called "hot swap". IntelliJ offers you to reload your changed classes every time you compile your application while it's running under a debugger. You can also trigger this explicitly using the Run | Reload Changed Classes menu item.

Comment: Thanks man! I used to just 'run' the application, so the 'Reload Changed Classes' were always not highlighted, noticed now that actually debugging the application will make that clickable (;